Hadamard product decomposition with lower rank matrices
Given integers $k$ and $l$ and a matrix $A$ of rank $kl$, can we always find a matrix $B$ of rank $k$ and a matrix $C$ of rank $l$, such that $A$ is the Hadamard product of $B$ and $C$, namely $A=B \odot C$?
For example, when $k=2$ and $l=2$ and $A$ is the 4 by 4 identity matrix,
\begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
we can find $B$ of rank 2 and $C$ of rank 2:
\begin{equation*}
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}, C = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
satisfying $A=B \odot C$.
Can we find $B$ and $C$ in the general case for any given $A$ and $k$, $l$?

I'm confused by the close vote -- is there an obvious solution to this problem that shows it's not research-level? I might be missing something, but I don't see an obvious solution, and some recent research has considered problems like this (e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01449).

There is a new paper published in May 2024 claiming that it cannot be done for arbitrary matrices. They did not give a specific example, but only provided high level intuitions. But their argument looked pretty convincing.
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10618-024-01033-y
